# UITapGestureRecognizer only detects a control tapped if tapped in the top half of the control

Tags: ios, hittest, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a type of "Help mode" on my iOS app.  When the user taps the help button, touches to the screen are intercepted by a UITapGestureRecognizer and if it is on a control, a little popup appears with help info.

My problem however is that the application only detects that I have tapped a control if I tap in the upper half of the control.  I use hitTest:withEvent: to determine which view was touched:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:nil];
UIView* touchedView = [self.view hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
```

UILabels are especially hard to hit successfully.

The View contains a navigationbar at the top but is fairly standard.  Has anyone had a similar issue?  Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the location of the touch in your view, not in the window (which is what you get when you specify `nil` as the view).

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:self.view];
UIView* touchedView = [self.view hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Could you explain why it partially works when I get the touch in the window?

Comment: In that case the point's y values are wrong by some offset -- probably related to the height of the status bar and/or the navigation bar. Sometimes you get lucky and you hit the "correct" view even with the wrong point.

Comment: I have the same problem that my UIImageView with UITapRecognizer only reports TouchEvents from the second half of its height, 'though I use `CGPoint location = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:sender.view];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:sender];`